# ASP.NET Trouble importing a DLL

Tags: asp.net, dllimport

I'm having a lot of trouble importing a DLL to use.
I have an aspx page with no code behind, no virtual directories.

All I know about the DLL is it's filename 'GenerateExcel.dll' and namespace 'Xander.Utilities'. How do I import it with either of these

```
<%@ Assembly Src="./bin/GenerateExcel.dll" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Xander.Utilities" %>
```

It's not working. I read the other threads on SO and still having trouble.

[alt text http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/8021/62535719.gif](http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/8021/62535719.gif)

EDIT:
I use it like this:

```
<script runat="server">

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //...
            Xander.Utilities.ExcelMaker em = new Xander.Utilities.ExcelMaker();
            //...        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to do an `<%@ Import Namespace="Xander.Utilities" %>` and then put the DLL in the root's bin folder.

Comment: Which file did you put that line into?

Comment: The ASPX page; for this small project there were no codebehinds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work as I don't have your assembly, but you could try with or without the TagPrefix:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="GenerateExcel" Namespace="Xander.Utilities" TagPrefix="Util" %>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should do it. Would have been my answer had you not beaten me to the punch! +1

Comment: You might need to register the assembly in your Web.config file, or you could always add a code behind page...

Comment: I see that the DLL shows up in your bin directory. Did you add the DLL as a reference?

Answer (score 1):

to call a dll from your program you need to include the System.Runtime.InteropServices classes

try:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices 
[DllImport("name.dll")]
private static extern int FunctionNameInDll();
```